# how can i set isolation level with propel?

Tags: php, mysql, innodb, propel, isolation

i use mysql, php on propel.

i have used transaction row lock on mysql with native SQL query(e.g. SELECT FOR UPDATE).
and now , I'm using 
[propel](http://propelorm.org/) 
to use ORM.

but propel is not support row lock by
[propel transaction limitations](http://propelorm.org/documentation/06-transactions.html)
.

Here is 
[MYSQL InnoDB Lock Modes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-lock-modes.html)
.

any ideas for overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Propel does not support this, the only solution I see would be to execute raw SQL.